# Is the tense of the latter part of the sentence correct?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, future

- *He couldn't foresee devoting himself to anything other than that passionate desire, even if the fire eventually burns him down.*

Is 'burns him down' correct? The speaker is okay with the fire burning him down in the future if that is the consequence of following his passion.

Comment: _.. should eventually burn .._

Comment: It's fine the way it is. Don't change it.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't is the past tense of 'can't'; the situation being described is in the past; the burning down was a hypothetical possible consequence; the correct verb form for 'burn' is the future in the past (would burn): he couldn't foresee devoting himself to anything other than that passionate desire, even if the fire would eventually burn him down."

[Future in past](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/futureinpast.html)

Comment: "I couldn't see myself doing it, even if I would lose" means though I know I will lose I still wouldn't do it. "i couldn't see myself doing it, even if I lost" means that I wouldn't do it and also I am unsure if I will lose. If my meanings are correct then I would like to convey the second meaning on the sentence in question.

Comment: @PsyPhi - Using the "future in the past", to which I linked an explanation, the  "would" after "if" applies to the consequence, not the action. It means it was definitely going to happen, if I did the thing. I knew that if I lit the fuse of the dynamite, it would explode.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here: backshift both clauses, or keep the original tense.

Assuming the original utterance was:

*I can't forsee devoting myself to anything other than that passionate desire, even if the fire eventually burns me down.*

Then you can backshift:

*He said that...*

*he **couldn't** forsee...fire eventually **burnt**...*

or not:

*he **can't** forsee...fire eventually **burns**...*

Both leave it open as to whether he is burnt down by the fire in the end. The outcome can clearly be questioned in both cases.

The addition of a modal auxiliary verb just adds modal meaning to the sentence that wasn't there in the first place.